# Hover image description on image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, hover

I am no expert in PHP, javascript and js; so I am hoping someone can help me in easy language terms. I have just developed my first wordpress site and changed the code immensely, using this forum - thanks heaps so far!

The site: http://www.heritageglass.com.au

**My request: text (description of image in media library) hovering over image.**

Just like this [website](http://www.redearth.com/complexion/primer.html) or this [plugin](http://coryschires.com/jquery-hover-caption-plugin/), I have found several questions on this site that refer to my issue but they haven't seemed to help or I don't exactly know where to place this as it's grabbing `the_title` and I want `the_description`. Is there such a term?

**PHP code in portfolio.php template:**

```
<div data-id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-type="<?php
  $categories = get_the_category();
  $count = count($categories);
  $i=1;
  foreach($categories as $category) {
      echo str_replace('-', '', $category->slug);
      if ($i<$count) echo ' '; $i++;} ?>" class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>
      <?php
        $categories = get_the_category();
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            echo str_replace('-', '', $category->slug).' '; } ?> project portfolio-item-wrap">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <a class="portfolio-item-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-image' ); ?></a>
        <?php } ?>


        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <p>
            <?php
            $categories = get_the_category(); 
            $temp = array();
            foreach($categories as $category) {
                if ($category->category_parent == 0) continue;
                $temp[] = str_replace('-', '', $category->name); 
            } 
            echo implode(", ", $temp);
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found this: [Text over image using jquery and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031602/text-over-image-using-jquery-and-css)
and added the script in the header.php. And used my .portfolio-item and .portfolio-item-img instead of .wrapper  and .description - but that didn't do anything.

Hoping someone can lead me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a lots of single-direct-function-calls embedded in HTML markup, e.g. `the_ID()`, `the_permalink()`, etc. Are you sure these functions **echo out** something instead of **return** something?

Comment: Not sure what your issue is exactly from your description, but I do know that js is short for JavaScript...

Comment: Sorry, meant jquery. ANd in regards to the  single-direct-function-calls, all this code is untouched from the wordpress theme I purchased. Asking the author is considered customisation.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a search on the [WordPress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-image-4) I found this from four years ago, not sure if it's what you need, but it might point you in the right direction.

```
$img_desc = $image->post_excerpt;
```

Comment: Thank you @Revent! Now that is one thing sorted. I just need to find the right script to carry out the function I want... any recommendations on that?

Comment: Hi @Revent, replacing the_title with post_content didn't work. Any other ideas? I got it to hover the_title so that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you....

http://www.net-kit.com/10-jquery-caption-plugins/#

http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/jquery-image-hover-effects/

Comment: Thank you. I found these and used some of the code - didn't get it to work. For the html, I can't add 'title' and 'description' to each thumbnail I have on the projects page. I need to put in a php code that grabs the post_content of each image. Any ideas on how to do that?


`<div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="image.gif" alt="title" title="" width="125" height="125"/></a>
        <div class="caption">
            <a href="">Title</a>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>`

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/showing-post-title-as-overlay-on-featured-image-on-hover

Comment: This is also the same question, I think it will solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179412/css-hover-over-on-thumbnails-in-wordpress

Comment: I have tried that already with the following code and it didn't work. The title just got repeated above each other.

`<a class="portfolio-item-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-image' ); ?></a>
          <?php } ?>
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
          
          <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4> `

Comment: I got it to work:


`<a class="portfolio-item-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-image' ); ?>
                  </a>`

Though I don't want the_title, I want the description or caption of the image as I already have the title underneath the image...

Answer (score 0):

When editing a post, add two custome field, one for title, one for descritption.
Our code goes like this:

```
$dataType = '';
$divClass = '';

$categories = get_the_category();
$count = count($categories); 
$i=1; 
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $dataType .= str_replace('-', '', $category->slug); 
    $divClass .= str_replace('-', '', $category->slug).' ';
    if ($i<$count) $dataType.= ' ';
    $i++;
}

$metaList = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
$title = isset($metaList['title']) ? $metaList['title'] : '';
$description = isset($metaList['description']) ? $metaList['description'] : '';

// now we have title and description for the thumb!
?>
<div data-id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-type="<?php echo $dataType;?>"
    class="post-<?php the_ID(); echo $divClass;?>  project portfolio-item-wrap">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <a class="portfolio-item-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-image' ); ?>
            </a>
        <?php } ?>


        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <p>
            <?php
                $temp = array();
                foreach($categories as $category) {
                    if ($category->category_parent == 0) continue;
                    $temp[] = str_replace('-', '', $category->name); 
                } 
                echo implode(", ", $temp);
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have replaced the <div data-id etc > in my portfolio.php file, but what dod I do with the $dataType above it? Place it in the header.php with <script> tags?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer after sooooo much research.

This is the answer: [How do I get the featured image description from my wordpress page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907810/how-do-i-get-the-featured-image-description-from-my-wordpress-page)

enter the the_post_thumbnail_caption(); within the span tags and set your span tags class in css.

done.

Thanks to all of you for your help!